# Queue-based Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, bellman-ford

i'm trying to understand how this algorithm works.

given a question to search the paths from a source s to all the vertices in the graph ,

I thought  that i have to proceed as follows:

```
if no cycle in the graph: 
     topological sort of the graph 
     one iteration to calculate the shortest path

else if there is a cycle in the graph:
     put s in the queue 
     v=q.deque
     while q is not empty
        relax v
```

My question are :

Is my proceeding good or i have to change it.

When i must check that there is a negative cycle?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your code for the acyclic one seems correct but depends on what do you mean by `one iteration to calculate the shortest path`.. If the graph is acyclic (i.e., a DAG) then topological sort will allow us to visit each vertex `v` once (after examining all of its predecessors) and update `dist[v]` to its minimum distance. This is done in linear time O(V+E). So your DAG algorithm should look somehow similar to this

```
  DAG_CASE:   
  topological sort of V
  for each u\in V following the topological sorting
    for each edge (u,v)
      relax(u,v)
```

For the code of directed cyclic graphs (with no negative cycles), you are not relaxing an edge and not updating/checking its end points.. I am not familiar with the queued version of the BF algorithm. All I can say is that you need to make sure that a vertex `v` is in the queue whenever you realize that one of its predecessors (i.e. `u`) is not *done* yet. So your code should `enqueue` and `dequeue` some vertices under certain conditions (while relaxing the edges). I think you already know the non-queued version of the algorithm which is obvious.

> When i must check that there is a negative cycle?

BF algorithm over a source `s` returns either the shortest paths from `s` to every other vertex or a failure indicating that there is a negative cycle. Following execution, If there is an edge that is not relaxed then there is a negative cycle.

Comment: thnk you , all you said is just , i'm working to get a good belman ford algorithm

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember details of Bellman-Ford, but basically, assume you have `n` edges and `m` vertex,

```
for e = 1 to n-1
     iterate tru each vertex and apply the formula
```

This part can be found on the internet easily.

Related to `When i must check that there is a negative cycle?`, you will do one more iteration and if any value in the last array(the array after `n-1-th iteration`) changes, you will say there is negative cycle, if nothing changes, it indicates there is no negative cycle.

This [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTW2yFYd1Nc) explains Bellman-Ford well with an example.

Comment: thank you but my question was about fifo belman algorithm , it improves belman ford algorithm  any way many thanks.

Comment: It s been some time, i learnt those, so that s all I remember. You are welcome